# AttributeError Despite Attribute Being Present

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a minesweeper game and I have two classes: Tile and Minesweeper.

```
class Tile:

    bomb: bool
    value: int
    revealed: bool

    def _init__(self):
        self.bomb = False
        self.revealed = False
        self.value = 0
```

```
class Minesweeper:

    board = []

    def add_bombs_and_values(self) -> None:
        for i in range(10):
            x, y = random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)
            while self.board[x][y].bomb: 
                x, y = random.randint(0, 10), random.randint(0, 10)
            self.board[x][y].bomb = True
            for row in range(x-1, x+1):
                for bomb in range(y-1, y+1):
                    if self.board[row][bomb]:
                        self.board[row][bomb].value += 1

    def create_board(self) -> None:
        for i in range(10):
            self.board.append([])
            for j in range(10):
                self.board[i].append(Tile())
        self.add_bombs_and_values()

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_board()

game1 = Minesweeper()
```

Whenever I create an instance of Minesweeper, it get an attribute error for 'bomb' even though its defined in the Tile class. Heres the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\pythonProject\main.py", line 64, in <module>
    game1 = Minesweeper()
  File "\pythonProject\main.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.create_board()
  File "\pythonProject\main.py", line 39, in create_board
    self.add_bombs_and_values()
  File "\pythonProject\main.py", line 26, in add_bombs_and_values
    while self.board[x][y].bomb:
AttributeError: 'Tile' object has no attribute 'bomb'
```

I dont really know whats causing this so I was hoping someone could help

Comment: You misspelled `__init__`, you're missing an underscore

Comment: also, when you use `random.randint(0, 10)` to generate indices, it can produce `10` as a value, which is out of bounds for your board index (since you're creating a 10x10 board, the valid indices are `0` through `9`). This can be easily fixed with `random.randint(0, 9)`.

also, also, the loop that increments the value for surrounding tiles doesn't properly include the end value because Python ranges are exclusive at the end, so you should iterate from `x-1` to `x+2` and `y-1` to `y+2`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I always get confused on loops and what values are actually included in ranges lol